# RabbitMQ Dequeue() method returns proper data and clears the rest of the queue. Why?

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm trying to use RabbitMQ queue to store and deliver messages to my application. When I use Dequeue() method on consumer (QueueingBasicConsumer type) to receive first few messages from queue (Dequeue() in loop), I'm getting then, but queue is cleaned. What is the reason? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code goes here:

```
public Model.Message GetMessages(int limit) 
{
    List<Model.Message> result;

    using(var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection())
    using(var channel = connection.CreateModel()) 
    {
        var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
        channel.BasicConsume("queueName", true, consumer);

        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++)
        {
            BasicDeliverEventArgs messages = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
            var body = ea.Body;
            //messages deserialization and so on... 
            //I'm getting proper value here, but queue becomes empty.
            result.Add(deserializedObject);
         }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: The Queue.Dequeue() method will block the thread until a message has been delivered into the queue. You can extract the message byte array from the BasicDeliverEventArgs object. The Auto-acknowledgement will release the message from the queue and will allow you to receive the next message.

Comment: Read about message acknowledgments here: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html